How to infer arguments types of a multiple signature method in TypeScript?
I use various Capacitor plugins in my Angular app.
They basically consists on methods, and also listeners. Here comes an example from Keyboard plugin :
addListener(eventName: 'keyboardWillShow', listenerFunc: (info: KeyboardInfo) => void): Promise<PluginListenerHandle> & PluginListenerHandle;

addListener(eventName: 'keyboardDidShow', listenerFunc: (info: KeyboardInfo) => void): Promise<PluginListenerHandle> & PluginListenerHandle;

addListener(eventName: 'keyboardWillHide', listenerFunc: () => void): Promise<PluginListenerHandle> & PluginListenerHandle;

addListener(eventName: 'keyboardDidHide', listenerFunc: () => void): Promise<PluginListenerHandle> & PluginListenerHandle;

I created a method that calls these addListener methods, but I don't know how to type it to achieve what I want :
myMethod(Keyboard, 'keyboardWillShow') // return type : Observable<KeyboardInfo>
myMethod(Keyboard, 'keyboardWillHide') // return type : Observable<void>
myMethod(Keyboard, 'nonexisting') // TS Error

I want to type my method in a way that it accepts plugin in first argument, and only accepts in second arg event names for which an addListener overload exists and accept it as its first arg.
I also want, if possible, to infer the type of the callback argument according to the event name.
For now, I have no idea of how to achieve this.
type CapacitorPlugin = {
  addListener: (eventName: any, listener: (event: any) => void) => Promise<PluginListenerHandle> & PluginListenerHandle
}

...

export function fromCapacitorListener(plugin: CapacitorPlugin, eventName: unknown): Observable<any> { /* ... */ }


Here is the typescript example demonstrating, multiple return types based on an input parameter.
First we define the events in a type.
type TypeName = "keyboardWillShow" | "keyboardDidShow" | "keyboardWillHide" | "keyboardDidHide";

Then we define interface that contains the return types. Then we can use T extends "keyboardWillShow" to conditionally set the return types.
type ObjectType<T extends TypeName> =
    T extends "keyboardWillShow" ? Observable<KeyboardInfo> :
    T extends "keyboardDidShow" ? Observable<void> :
    T extends "keyboardWillHide" ? Observable<string> :
    T extends "keyboardDidHide" ? Observable<number> :
    never;

We can use Generics of Typescript to obtain the type of the parameter, then feed it to ObjectType, which will give use the generic object types.
function myMethod<T extends TypeName>(model: Keyboard, parameter: T): ObjectType<T> {
    return '';
}
const keyboard = new Keyboard();
const test1 = myMethod(keyboard, "keyboardWillShow");
const test2 = myMethod(keyboard, "keyboardDidShow");
const test3 = myMethod(keyboard, "keyboardWillHide");
const test4 = myMethod(keyboard, "keyboardDidHide");

Full Code:
export class Keyboard {

}


type TypeName = "keyboardWillShow" | "keyboardDidShow" | "keyboardWillHide" | "keyboardDidHide";

export interface KeyboardInfo { }

export interface Observable<T> {
    test: T;
}

type ObjectType<T extends TypeName> =
    T extends "keyboardWillShow" ? Observable<KeyboardInfo> :
    T extends "keyboardDidShow" ? Observable<void> :
    T extends "keyboardWillHide" ? Observable<string> :
    T extends "keyboardDidHide" ? Observable<number> :
    never;

function myMethod<T extends TypeName>(model: Keyboard, parameter: T): ObjectType<T> {
    return '';
}
const keyboard = new Keyboard();
const test1 = myMethod(keyboard, "keyboardWillShow");
const test2 = myMethod(keyboard, "keyboardDidShow");
const test3 = myMethod(keyboard, "keyboardWillHide");
const test4 = myMethod(keyboard, "keyboardDidHide");

Typescript Playground Demo

Thanks for your Replay, but in your code your explictly declare type names, is it possible to directly infer them from an existing Keyboard class with methods signatures like I described in my post ?

@FabienLH As far as I know no, this guides typescript to a type, if typescript cannot infer the type by itself.
